# razercfg does not recognize Razer BlackWidow V3 Tenkeyless

Tags: linux, keyboard, driver, manjaro, lsusb

I got a new keyboard, a Razer BlackWidow V3 Tenkeyless and in `lsusb` it sahws up like:

```
lsusb
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 046d:c534 Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0a5c:21e8 Broadcom Corp. BCM20702A0 Bluetooth 4.0
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 1532:0a24 Razer USA, Ltd Razer BlackWidow V3 Tenkeyless
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 046d:0826 Logitech, Inc. HD Webcam C525
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 058f:6362 Alcor Micro Corp. Flash Card Reader/Writer
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

yet `razercfg -s` does not seem to be able to see it, nor does `qrazercfg` (tried the former with sudo too). What do I do for the tool to recognize my new keyboard?

Comment: Do you have the latest drivers installed? I believe that the Razer BlackWidow V3 Tenkeyless support was added only 8 weeks ago.
https://github.com/openrazer/openrazer/

Comment: yeah, from the AUR, I installed package `openrazer-driver-dkms` which is of version 3.1.0

Comment: Have you tried the troubleshooting guide? https://github.com/openrazer/openrazer/wiki/Troubleshooting

Comment: Went through it but didn't help, rebooted too... I might end up opening a ticket.... or I move this over into the unix groups....